# type 'Sector' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast flutter problem?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to display my Tabs using a sectors' list (Sector model) which I'm getting from Api like shown bellow:

```
SizedBox(
                    child: DefaultTabController(
                      initialIndex: 1,
                      length: sectorsProvider.sectorList.length,
                      child: DecoratedBox(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          //This is for background color
                          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
                          //This is for bottom border that is needed
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.4),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: ListView(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          children: [
                            TabBar(
                                isScrollable: true,
                                indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                                controller: _tabController,
                                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                                indicatorWeight: 3.0,
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 22.0,
                                ),
                                // unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.black26,),
                                tabs: (sectorsProvider.sectorList as List<Sector>).map((index) => Tab(text: sectorsProvider.sectorList[index as int].name)).toList(),
                                ),
                          ], 
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I had the following error :
type 'Sector' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast..

thanks for help!

Comment: `Iterable.map` passes the *element* to the callback, not an index.  Since you're calling .`map` on a `List<Sector>`, the argument will already be a `Sector`.  You probably want: `...map((sector) => Tab(text: sector.name)).toList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
index as int
```

The plain fact that your compiler tells you this is not an `int` should make you think twice about what you are doing.

`index` in this case is of type `Sector`, because the callback you provide to `map` takes an element of the `Iterable`. In your case, since it's a `List<Sector>` that is a `Sector`.

So `sectorsProvider.sectorList[index as int].name` is not needed, all you need is `index.name`. Although it might be better to rename the variable:

```
tabs: (sectorsProvider.sectorList as List<Sector>).map((sector) => Tab(text: sector.name)).toList()
```

The fact that you need to cast `sectorsProvider.sectorList` to `List<Sector>` looks fishy, too. You shouldn't have to cast anything. Any time you do this, look for the improvement that would make the cast redundant, instead of casting.